# DROP INDEX never finishes

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, indexing

I'm trying to drop an index that I have but when I execute the statement it just runs and runs (up to 30 mins before i stopped it last time).  Has anyone ever run into this before?  Any suggestions on how to free it up for deletion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Adam Machanic's awesome [WhoIsActive script](http://www2.sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2009/12/03/who-is-active-v9-57-fast-comprehensive-dmv-collection.aspx) to find out which other transaction is blocking your DROP statement, then wait for that to finish, ask the user to disconnect or just `KILL` the session.

Comment: That script is awesome.  Thanks for pointing me to it.  Found the blocking session.  Can't kill it unfortunately but at least i know what's going on.

Comment: Latest version here, http://sqlblog.com/files/folders/beta/entry42453.aspx. This guy saved my life, the Database Engine Tuning Advisor was trying to drop an index on a very large table.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have an idle transaction that holds a lock, perhaps?

Comment: DBCC OPENTRAN will show open transactions. You could also pop open Activity Monitor, or run sp_Who2 and see who is blocking your drop.